# How Two date range filters in Magento SOAP

Tags: php, magento, soap

I need some help about date range filters in Magento SOAP (Webservice).

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://website/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$apiuser="user";
$apikey="passwd";

$sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);

$params = array( 'filter' => array(
array('key' => 'created_at','value' => array(
'from' => '2015-07-13 00:00:00',
'to' => '2015-07-13 23:59:59'))));

$vend=$client->salesOrderList($sess_id, $params);

print_r($vend);

?>
```

I tried use `complex_filter` but i got an segmentation failure.

Someone have an working sample of date range filter? And is better to use soap v1 or v2?

Answer (score 2):

send the params in this way I hope it works for you

```
$params = array('complex_filter' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'created_at',
                    'value' => array(
                        'key' => 'from',
                        'value' => '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
                    ),
                ),

                    array(
                    'key' => 'created_at',
                    'value' => array(
                        'key' => 'to',
                        'value' => '2019-06-21 23:59:59'
                    ),
                ),
            ));
```